# InterlockedSubtract workaround - memory barriers

Tags: hlsl, memory-barriers

I have a situation where I would love to have an InterlockedSubtract function in HLSL. InterlockedAdd works fine for integers, but I'm stuck using a RWByteAddressBuffer of uints - I'm using every single bit, and I would rather not resort to having an encode/decode function to make ints behave exactly like uints.

My current workaround looks like this:

```
uint oldValue = Source.Load(oldParent, y);
Source.InterlockedMin(oldParent, oldValue - 1, y);
```

The issue is that I understand that it is possible for these operations to be confused across several threads, like so:

```
Thread 1:                   Thread 2:
o1 = Source.Load(l)                                                      l = 10, o1 = 10
                            o2 = Source.Load(l)                          l = 10, o2 = 10
Source.InterlockedMin(l, o1 - 1)                                         l = 9
                            Source.InterlockedMin(l, o2 - 1)             l = 9
```

These would only decrement the value once, despite the two calls.

As I understand it, I can't just make it a one-liner, as the compiled instructions could desync anyway.

Is there a workaround I'm missing? I could refactor my code to use another uint as a subtraction counter, then use another kernel to subtract those from the actual counts, but I'd much prefer to keep it within one kernel.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do `sub(x)` as `add(-x)`?  Maybe I'm missing something since I'm not familiar with HLSL.

Comment: It would work perfectly to do add(-x) were it not that the field is locked to the type of the data it is pointing at - an unsigned integer. I could attempt to overflow using InterlockedAdd, but I can't find any documentation on the behavior of InterlockedAdd when it comes to overflows. If it takes me long enough to solve this problem I will try that, but for the moment I'm using a separate counter for subtractions, then another kernel to perform the subtraction non-atomically all at once.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if any computing hardware didn't provide unsigned atomic add that wraps around, possibly providing the carry-out as an additional result.

Comment: I will test overflow tomorrow - it would be very convenient!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PeterCordes you were absolutely right.
I did something very simple to test:

HLSL

```
#pragma kernel Overflow

RWByteAddressBuffer buff;

uint ByteIndex(uint3 id)
{
    return (id.x + id.y * 8) * 4;
}

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void Overflow (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint originalValue;
    buff.InterlockedAdd(ByteIndex(id), 1, originalValue);
}
```

And C#

```
    public ComputeShader shade;
    private ComputeBuffer b;
    private int kernel;
    private uint[] uints = new uint[64];

    private void Start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { uints[i] = 4294967294; }
        for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { Debug.Log(uints[i]); }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            b = new ComputeBuffer(64, sizeof(uint));
            b.SetData(uints);
            kernel = shade.FindKernel("Overflow");
            shade.SetBuffer(kernel, Shader.PropertyToID("buff"), b);
            shade.Dispatch(kernel, 1, 1, 1);
            b.GetData(uints);
            b.Dispose();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { Debug.Log(uints[i]); }
        }        
    }
```

This clearly exhibits the desired behavior.

It would be nice if this behavior was documented in HLSL, but at least I know it now.